# Calculate total sum of dynamically added items to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to calculate the line total for each item using the **itemPrice* Qty** fields, the line amount is to be auto populated in the **linePrice** textbox. After which the grand total is then auto populated to the **priceTotal** field by summing up all the line prices.

I am having a challenge getting each **Qty** and **itemPrice** textbox value into my JavaScript function since the name(s) is/are **Qty0, Qty1, Qty2...** and **itemPrice0, itemPrice1,..** depending on the added row, and also getting the final calculations into the respective textboxes.

Below is my code.

```js
function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode != 46 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)))
    return false;
  return true;
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("keyup", ".Qty", calculateTot);
  $("button").click(function() {
    addrow('tb')
  });
});

function calculateTot() {

  var sum = 0;
  var price = document.getElementById('itemPrice').value;
  var qtyPur = parseFloat(this.value);

  $(".Qty").each(function() {

    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      linePR = price * qtyPur;
    }

  });
  $("#linePrice").val(linePR.toFixed(2));
  calculateSum();
}


function calculateSum() {

  var sum = 0;
  $(".linePrice").each(function() {

    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }

  });
  $("#priceTotal").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1,
    j = 1;
  $("#add_row").click(function() {
    if (i < 10) {
      $('#addr' + i).html("<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td><b>Select Item</b></td><td colspan='1'><select name='Sub_Name" + i + "' class='form-control'><option value=''>Select Item</option><option value='1000001'>Item A</option><option value='1000002'>Item B</option><option value='1000003'>Item C</option><option value='1000004'>Item D</option></select></td><td><input type='text' name='itemPrice" + i + "' id='itemPrice" + j + "' class='itemPrice form-control' placeholder='Unit Price'></td><td><input type='number' name='Qty" + i + "' id='Qty" + j + "' class='Qty form-control' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)' placeholder='Quantity'></td><td><input type='text' name='linePrice" + i + "' id='linePrice" + j + "' class='linePrice form-control' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)' placeholder='Line Price' readonly></td>");

      $('#tab_add').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
      i++;
      j++;
      $('#delete_row').show();
    } else {
      alert("You can only add upto a maximum of 10 items")
      $('#add_row').hide();
    }
  });
  $("#delete_row").click(function() {
    if (i > 1) {
      var r = confirm('Do you want to delete this item?');
      if (r == true) {
        $("#addr" + (i - 1)).html('');
        i--;
        $('#add_row').show();
      }
    } else {
      alert("Entry cannot be deleted")
      $('#delete_row').hide();
    }

  });
});
```

```html
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_add">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><b>Customer Name</b></td>
      <td colspan="1">
        <select name="Per_Name[]" class="form-control">
          <option value="">Select Customer</option>
          <option value="2000001">John Doe</option>
          <option value="2000002">Jane Doe</option>
          <option value="2000003">Tom Harry</option>
          <option value="2000004">Steve Jobs</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='addr0'>
      <td><b>1</b></td>
      <td><b>Select Item</b></td>
      <td colspan="1">
        <select name="Sub_Name[]" class="form-control">
          <option value="">Select Item</option>
          <option value="1000001">Item A</option>
          <option value="1000002">Item B</option>
          <option value="1000003">Item C</option>
          <option value="1000004">Item D</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="itemPrice0" id="itemPrice0" class="itemPrice form-control" placeholder="Unit Price"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="Qty0" id="Qty0" class="Qty form-control" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" placeholder="Quantity"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="linePrice0" id="linePrice0" class="linePrice form-control" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" placeholder="Line Price" readonly></td>
      <th>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;width:33%;" id="add_row" title="Add More Item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;width:33%;" id="delete_row" title="Remove Item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></a>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr id='addr1'></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <tr id="finRow">
    <td colspan="2" width="75%"><b>TOTAL</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="priceTotal" id="priceTotal" class="row-total form-control" disabled></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reduce the amount of DOM traversal that you have to do to accomplish this, I suggest adding `data-*` attributes to your elements so that you can get the index and use that to reference the other elements directly.

```
<td><input type="text" name="itemPrice0" id="itemPrice0" data-index="0" class="itemPrice form-control" placeholder="Unit Price"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="Qty0" id="Qty0" data-index="0" class="Qty form-control" onkeypress="if(!isNumberKey(event)){return false;}" placeholder="Quantity"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="linePrice0" id="linePrice0" data-index="0" class="linePrice form-control" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" placeholder="Line Price" readonly></td>
```

Then in your `$("#add_row").click(function() {` function we add `data-index='"+j+"'` when creating the new elements ...

```
$('#addr' + i).html("<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td><b>Select Item</b></td><td colspan='1'><select name='Sub_Name" + i + "' class='form-control'><option value=''>Select Item</option><option value='1000001'>Item A</option><option value='1000002'>Item B</option><option value='1000003'>Item C</option><option value='1000004'>Item D</option></select></td><td><input type='text' name='itemPrice" + i + "' id='itemPrice" + j + "' data-index='"+j+"' class='itemPrice form-control' placeholder='Unit Price'></td><td><input type='number' name='Qty" + i + "' id='Qty" + j + "' data-index='"+j+"' class='Qty form-control' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)' placeholder='Quantity'></td><td><input type='text' name='linePrice" + i + "' id='linePrice" + j + "' data-index='"+j+"' class='linePrice form-control' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)' placeholder='Line Price' readonly></td>");
```

Finally, change your `keyup` handler to ...

```
$("#tab_add").on("keyup", ".Qty", function(e){

    var qtyPur = parseFloat(this.value);

    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {

        // this is where use use the data-index attribute to dynamically generate the target element ids
        $("#linePrice"+$(this).data('index')).val(
            parseFloat($("#itemPrice"+$(this).data('index')).val()) * qtyPur
        );
     }

    calculateSum()

});
```

[See Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/prLjvj8d/)

Comment: Thanks Patrick, this is perfect. I will make the necessary changes.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

This part of code will calculate linePrice of each row:

```
$("tr").each(function() {
  if ($(this).children("td").length) {
    $($($(this).children("td")[5]).children("input")[0]).val(

      (($($($(this).children("td")[4]).children("input")[0]).val()) ? Number($($($(this).children("td")[4]).children("input")[0]).val()) : 0) *
      (($($($(this).children("td")[3]).children("input")[0]).val()) ? Number($($($(this).children("td")[3]).children("input")[0]).val()) : 0)

    )
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

function grosschanged_total1(a) {

```
        var str = a;
        var res = str.split("_");
        //alert(res[2]);
        var result = res[2];

        var rate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Gridview1_txtgross_" + result).value) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("Gridview1_txtrate_" + result).value);
        var scale77 = 2;
       // rate = roundNumberV2(rate, scale77);


        var gresult = 0.00;

        if(isNaN(rate)){
            gresult=  document.getElementById("Gridview1_txttotal_" + result).value = "";

        } else{
            gresult=  document.getElementById("Gridview1_txttotal_" + result).value = parseFloat(Math.round(rate * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

        }
        //GridView1_txtinvamt_0

        var gfresult = parseFloat(gresult);

        var ggresult = 0.00;

        ggresult = gfresult + ggresult;

     //   $("[id*=lblGrandTotal]").html(ggresult);


        //GridView1_txtdelinvnum_0 + GridView1_txtinvamt_0 = GridView1_txtgrosspt_0
      //  Calculate();

        grosschanged_total1(a);

    }

    function Numerics(text) {

        var regexp = /^[0-9]*$/;

        if (text.value.search(regexp) == -1) {
            text.value = text.value.substring(0, (text.value.length - 1));
            alert('Numerics only allowed');
            if (text.value.search(regexp) == -1)
                text.value = "";
            text.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
```